# Problem with NSObject init method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a problem with the init() method of a standard NSObject. I wrote a class (EFAPersistence) which is a subclass of NSObject. EFAPersistance has a attribute called **efaDatabase**.

**EFAPersistence.h**

```
@interface EFAPersistence : NSObject {
  FMDatabase * efaDatabase;
}

@property (assign) FMDatabase * efaDatabase;
```

Everytime an instance of EFAPersistance is created I want to assign efaDatabase a value from my AppDelegate.

**EFAPersistence.m**

```
@implementation EFAPersistence

@synthesize efaDatabase;

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    efaDatabase = [[NSApp delegate] efaDatabase];
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

This way of assigning does not work. But it works if I put the code in a normal method. So I am sure that efaDatabase is correctly instantiated in my AppDelegate. It's just not working in my init() method. That's why I have the feeling that NSApp is not working inside the init() method.

That's how the important AppDelegate code looks like.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
  FMDatabase * efaDatabase;
}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    NSString * databasePath = 
      [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"efa" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    self.efaDatabase = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];

    if (![efaDatabase open]) {
      NSLog(@"Couldn't open database: %@", databasePath);
      // TODO: Create a database here
    }
    self.db = [[EFAPersistence alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}
```

As you can see I am calling the init method. I also affirmed this by using NSLog(). init() is called. The attribute I am trying to assign in EFAPersistence is also created before init() is called.

To sum everything up:

How can I make this work within the init() method so I do not have to write boiler plate code in all my methods of EFAPersistence?

Comment: Syntax note:  The proper way to refer to an instance method in Objective-C is -method:name:including:colons:, not method().  For example, -init or -databaseWithPath:, not init() or databaseWithPath().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me that your AppDelegate is unset when you try to create the `EFAPersistance` object the first time. This is on below line in AppDelegate.m

```
self.db = [[EFAPersistence alloc] init];
```

I imagine the app delegate is set after the `init` is done (returned).

Comment: I also think that NSApp is created/assigned or whatever after init(). The question is how to assign efaDatabase in EFAPersistences only once . There are other methods like awakeFromNib and viewDidLoad etc. But those are not available in a plain NSObject subclass.

Comment: @Jens How about doing `self.db.efaDatabase = efaDatabase;` right after the line I referred to above?

Comment: Setting efaDatabase on self.db, after instantiating it, worked. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

> This way of assigning does not work. But it works if I put the code in a normal method. So I am sure that efaDatabase is correctly instantiated in my AppDelegate. It's just not working in my init() method. That's why I have the feeling that NSApp is not working inside the init() method.

NSApp works fine.

Quoting epatel:

> I imagine the app delegate is set after the init is done (returned).

Correct. The nib loader completely instantiates each object (including the app delegate, if it's in a nib), *then* sets it as the value of any properties it's connected to. These are two separate operations; it will not set a not-yet-initialized object as the application delegate.

Quoting you (Jens) again:

> The question is how to assign `efaDatabase` in EFAPersistences only once . There are other methods like awakeFromNib and viewDidLoad etc. But those are not available in a plain NSObject subclass.

Incorrect. `awakeFromNib` is sent to *every* object in a nib after the object has been initialized.

That said, I'm curious as to why you have EFAPersistence in a nib. From its name, it doesn't sound interface-related. Shouldn't the app delegate own the EFAPersistence, and the EFAPersistence own the database directly?